# Kivy ReferenceListProperty with more than two arguments

Tags: python, kivy, rgba

I've just begun to use Kivy and was wondering if one could give a class a `ReferenceListProperty` with more than two components? For example, if I have `Numeric Properties` called `r`, `g`, `b` and `a`, and try to give my class such a property

```
color = ReferenceListProperty(r, g, b, a)
```

it tells me `b` and `a` are unexpected arguments. I'm aware I could just give it a `DictProperty` with keys equivalent to the `NumericProperties`, but having a 4-tuple `ReferenceListProperty` would be much more helpful. How would I go about doing this and if it cannot be done, what is the best alternative? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [kivy docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=referencelistproperty#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty) `ReferenceListProperty` is a property that allows the creation of a tuple containing other properties. Have you actually defined `r`,`g`,`b`,`a` as `NumericProperties`? The code snippet below runs without error:

```
from kivy.properties import ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

x = someValue
r = NumericProperty(x)
b = NumericProperty(x)
g = NumericProperty(x)
a = NumericProperty(x)
color = ReferenceListProperty(r,g,b,a)
```

Comment: yeah, I think there was something wrong with my linter cos it was yelling at me for having 4 arguments. Thanks anyway.